# LateInitializationError: Field '_timer@137128430' has not been initialized in flutter Null safe version

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm beginner for the flutter , I have added flowing code and flutter suggested to add late, I added  `late Timer _timer;`
after it showed me the following error

> LateInitializationError: Field '_timer@137128430' has not been
> initialized.

any solution for this?
Thanks

**code here**

```
  late Timer _timer;
  int _start = 60;

  //start timer
  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
          (Timer timer) {
        if (_start == 0) {
          setState(() {
            timer.cancel();
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _start--;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTimer();
    
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Not reproducible. I copied the code and ran the same on dartpad and its work.

Comment: @RohanThacker Hello buddy , i used flutter Null safe version

Comment: Same here, this code looks okay

Comment: @Are you sure ? :( but theres is not work

Comment: Yeah have you tried to restart the app?

Comment: no,   I will try It

Comment: Are you the timer that is not initialized is the one shown in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Please call startTimer() before super.initState() in the initState. Like below

```
 @override

 void initState() {

     startTimer();
     super.initState();
     
 }
```

Comment: The flutter docs explicitly says not to do that https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html :
_"Implementations of this method should start with a call to the inherited method, as in super.initState()."_

Answer (score 0):

Use `Timer? _timer;` instead of `late Timer _timer;`